# Android - Get app package name from app(3rd party) which start my app activity

Tags: android

Guys need help on this :(

ComponentName componentName = ShareCompat.getCallingActivity(this);

String callingPackage = ShareCompat.getCallingPackage(this);

I can get app package name from above code, if my APP A (com.demo.app.a) startActivityForResult() the APP B.

At APP B, i can get : com.demo.app.a

But, if APP B() opened by Google Chrome Browser(from Intent Action.View by scheme). Let's say my app support https scheme.

My APP B, can't retrieve Google Chrome Browser app package name.

Note: Google Chrome Browser just an example.

BaseActivity.this.getReferrer().getHost(), this return correct app package name that i want. But this only available API 22+

Any way for detect app package name, if my app opened with any 3rd-party app?

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My APP B, can't retrieve Google Chrome Browser app package name.

Correct. There is no requirement that an app include the `EXTRA_REFERRER` extra in any `Intent`, and even if they do, they can put a fake `Uri` in there.

> BaseActivity.this.getReferrer().getHost(), this return correct app package name that i want

Not necessarily. Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getReferrer()): "Note that this is not a security feature -- you can not trust the referrer information, applications can spoof it."

> Any way for detect app package name, if my app opened with any 3rd-party app?

No.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, I have one scenario : 

Web browser A > Load web page that contain link with button (https://www.test.com?val1="1"&val2="2") > click on button > call APP A > APP A (process data) > return "3" (1+2) > concat url  "https://www.test.com?result="3" >  Web browser A. 

Due to session/cookie issue, i must pass back to the Web browser A. 

startActivity() seem not helps , since user can choice Web browser B.

Any way for this? Thanks for your help :D

Comment: @DBMobisoftMobiSoft: Not only do you not know what Web browser A is, but you have no way of knowing if `startActivity(A)` would maintain your same session/cookie.